# How can I mark a method as discouraged in java?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm programming a Config class that reads a file and provides config parameters as a Map.
Parameters can be accessed by `conf.get("LogLevel")` or `conf.getLogLevel()`.

The first function just reads from the map and returns the value (that can be `null` or invalid) while the second function converts the value to a LogLevel and returns a default value when no valid value is given.

Therefore I want to discourage Programmers from using the genereral `get()`, but there are special cases where this method is useful so I cant just make it protected.
Right now I use `@Deprecated` but I dont think this is a good solution because it is only ment for methods that will be removed in the future. (Correct me if I'm wrong there, thats what SonarLint told me about the @Deprecated annotation)

```java
/**
 * @Deprecated When possible, use the key-specific getter instead
 */
public String get(String key) {
    return values.get(key);
}

public int getLogLevel() {
    return Log.getLogLevel(values.get(LOG_LEVEL), Log.getLogLevel(defaultValues.get(LOG_LEVEL)));
}
```

Comment: Define what you mean by 'good solution' that explains why the annotation provided explicitly for the purpose doesn't qualify.

Comment: You can also write something like `non-API` into your JavaDoc to tell people it's not for general public use.

Comment: Maybe you could make use of the _javadoc_ tag [@apiNote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673421/new-javadoc-annotation-apinote)

Comment: It's common practice to use `@Deprecated` as a warning even for methods that aren't being removed. See e.g. Guava's [`ImmutableList.remove()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#remove(int)) and [`FluentIterable.from(FluentIterable)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#from(com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable)), and Spring's [`NoOpPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/NoOpPasswordEncoder.html).

Answer (score 4):

Well, if `@Deprecated` is not the solution, you are left with only one option.  Put message that notes that the usage is "discouraged" (except for the special cases) into the javadocs ... and **hope** that people are going to read the javadocs.

Defining your own custom annotation will not help because you can't get your users to use an annotation processor that will recognize it.

Likewise, you can't do it via custom rules for FindBugs, PMD, Sonar and so forth because that requires your users to customize their installations of those products.

(Though ... if this is an in-house product and all of your users use a common CI server ... you could possibly do the checks in the CI server.  It depends if you can define custom rules that can reliably distinguish  the general "discouraged" use-cases from the special cases.  This will also entail convincing your co-workers that this is a good idea.)

---

In my opinion, the `@Deprecated` tag would be better than all of the above.  For the special cases, encourage people to *judiciously* add `@SuppressWarning("deprecation")` in the cases where the usage is necessary.

> I don't think this is a good solution because it is only meant for methods that will be removed in the future.

This is incorrect.  Possible future removal is only one of the *example* reasons for deprecation listed in the `@Deprecated` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Deprecated.html) (Java 11 version).  Other reasons listed there are:

- "the tagged element's usage is likely to lead to errors",
- "it may be changed incompatibly [...] in a future version",
- "it has been superseded by a newer, usually preferable alternative", or
- "it is obsolete".

Note that these are listed as *example* reasons ... which means that you *could* deprecate for other reasons.

This is also consistent with the older "when to deprecate" guidance [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html).

IMO, your "discouraged" scenario is covered by that.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived here and looking for android solution there's @Discouraged annotation in `androidx`